# Error message if no data entered in text box

Tags: vba, excel

Please suggest a vb code, that if the text box is left blank,and during TAB/Enter, the Error message box appears for each text box.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Sheets("Attendance").Select
   Range("a1").Select
   Do
      If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False Then
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      End If
   Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True

   ActiveCell.Value = Me.d.Value
   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
   ActiveCell.Value = Me.N.Value
   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
   ActiveCell.Value = Me.Salary.Value
   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
   ActiveCell.Value = Me.Remarks.Value
   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
   ActiveCell.Value = Me.IT.Value
   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
   ActiveCell.Value = Me.Outtime.Value
   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
   ActiveCell.Value = Me.Lunch.Value
   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
   ActiveCell.Value = Me.Advance.Value
   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
   ActiveCell.Value = Me.Paid.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: You have to use `if --- end if` for each text box `Exit` event.

Comment: you need to look at the textboxes and their leave event, then check their value<>"" or length>0

Comment: I created a form for data entry for attendance record of emplyee

Comment: I am very new to VBA, I tried this code from google search engine, please provide the code for at least 1 text box, lets say Salary textbox.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211378(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below sub carefully and try to do to your user form.

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
        If Me.TextBox1 = "" Then
            MsgBox "You must enter value!"
            Cancel = True
            Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks all For your support  

Comment: If you found it working for you, you should accept my answer.